# How to access a DataFrame created with PySpark using SparkR?

Tags: pyspark, sparkr, apache-spark-dataset

I created a PySpark DataFrame on Databricks.

```
%python 
# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/file.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema = "true"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ";"

# The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df1 = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)
```

Now I want to use df1 with SparkR

```
%r
library('SparkR')
df1
```

sparkR cannot use or find df1 created by PySpark.

```
Error in eval(parse(text = DATABRICKS_CURRENT_TEMP_CMD__)) : 
Error in eval(parse(text = DATABRICKS_CURRENT_TEMP_CMD__)) : 
  object 'df1' not found
```

How can I access pySpark Dataframes with sparkR and vice versa? Or each Dataframe is a completely different object?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the dataframe by R directly as it was created in different language workspace. Nevertheless, there is a way to copy it to R: through a temp view.

First you create a temp view from the pyspark dataframe:

```
%py 
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('pysp_df')
```

Then you load it to R using `sql(.)` function

```
%r 
library(SparkR)
df1 <- sql('select * from pysp_df')
```

Note that it is a different object so if you want to work with it using pyspark, you have to transfer it back to pyspark the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You defined df

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)
```

Why are you using df1 when you created a DataFrame df?

```
%r
library('SparkR')
df1
```

**To answer this**

> How can I access pySpark Dataframes with sparkR and vice versa? Or each Dataframe is a completely different object?

Refer

- **Differences**: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/12/28/10-things-i-wish-i-knew-before-using-apache-sparkr.html and
- **Spark & R data frame operations with SparkR**: https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/spark-r-data-frame-operations-sql-du1080rl5

Comment: I am sorry for the typo, it is suppose to be df1 in both code snippets. Thank you for these links: I will read them carefully.

Comment: Sorry but your references do not provide an answer to the question. They are about how to use sparkR and Dataframes and not about how to access a Dataframe created by pySpark by using sparkR.

Comment: If you read those articles then you must realize that, you cannot access.

Comment: As I said I read the references carefully, but as a newbie I might not understand what I read in the same way as you do. According to the Spark stack diagram (on the first reference you indicated) both sparkR and PySpark are two API languages that access commonly the SQL, Dataframe and Dataset from the analytical API. My understanding is that both languages API are interfacing the same Dataframe API, therefore I do not understand why a Dataframe object should be different if it was instanciated by one or another language. Could you please explain what am I thinking wrong here? Thank you!